# How to Remove White space after splitting String?

Tags: java, string, split

Hi i am splitting String with delimiter "," . The result containing white space. How can i remove this white space? why this white space is coming?

```
public class StringUtilsPractice  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString= "123,456";
    String[] splitedString= myString.split(",");
    List<String> splitedList= Arrays.asList(splitedString);
    List<String> filterValue=new ArrayList<String>();
    filterValue.add("123,456");
    boolean flag=filterValue.contains(splitedList);
    System.out.println("splitedList:"+splitedList);
    System.out.println("filterValue:"+filterValue);
    System.out.println("Flag::"+flag);
}
```

}

Result:
    splitedList:[123, 456]
    filterValue:[123,456]
    Flag::false

I am splitting by default one white space is adding. how can remove that white space. And result should return "true".

Comment: Are you sure `Arrays.asList` isn't adding a space between elements?

Comment: This is coming from the String representation of the List. _"The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space)."_

Comment: The elements are without whitespace, that's simply how it is displayed.

Comment: If you print each element individually, between quotations, you'll see that it worked as you expect. Whatever method you are using to *display* the result is causing that space to follow the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [line 442](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#442) of `AbstractCollection`. What you're looking at is the native `toString()` output of `List` (i.e., the string representation of `List`), which adds a comma for readability.

You can also see this in the JavaDoc for [`AbstractCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()):

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). **Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space)**. Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(Object)`. (emphasis mine)

If you iterated over the values yourself and printed them out, you will notice that there are no spaces.

Comment: i am using "contains" method it returning false. String A="123,456"; A.contains(myString)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is the value of `myString`?

Comment: myString= "123,456". Basically i am comparing 2 lists using contains method. comparing for sequence also.

Comment: You cannot compare lists like that.